# Even permutation in infinite symbol set

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

In finite set S , one one and  onto function from A to A is called permutation group. Corresponding even and odd permutation are defined but when set has infinite elements then how to check a given function is even permutation or odd.

Answer (score 1):

The terms 'even' or 'odd' permutations are only used in the finite case, i.e. when the set itself is finite or the set $\{s\in S | \sigma(s) \neq s\}$ is a finite subset of $S$, $\sigma$ being the permutation.

Comment: Then how one can define alternating group on infinite symbols set . Can we interpret this as even and odd function on infinite symbols set. Those function which are one one and onto and even function i .e f(-x)= f(x) belong to alternating group.

Comment: In the same way. The alternating group only consists of elements who keep only finitely many elements non-fixed. This has nothing to do with the 'even' and 'odd' from real functions, btw. so youre $f(x)=f(-x)$ is nonsense here.

Comment: Out of curiosity (because it just occurred to me). What is the index of the commutator subgroup of $S_X$ when $X$ is countably infinite? Does it becomes infinite, or is it even known?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It seems like every infinite symmetric group is perfect, so the index is always 1. The result seems to be due to Oystein Ore, look for "Some remarks on commutators", if you are interested. I haven't read it though.

Comment: Just some notation:  if $S$ is an infinite set, the set of permutations of $S$ fixing all but finitely many points is sometimes called the *finitary symmetric group* (to contrast it with the full symmetric group containing all permutations), and it contains the *finitary alternating group*.  As @Verdruss has pointed out, the full symmetric group on an infinite set has no corresponding alternating group.